# Why is my $R^2$ value negative in testing set?

Tags: r

I have this dataset:

```
middle_sub
   Ratio at Birth Unemployment Graduation Rate Literacy Rate Fertility Rate
1          108.19         2.16           83.86          89.9           2.63
2          104.34         1.32           89.28          90.8           2.58
3           98.42         1.46           98.36          92.1           2.43
4          114.12         1.51           97.10          91.2           2.49
5          107.95         1.20           98.14          90.3           2.30
6          104.19         1.03           87.61          90.4           2.26
7          117.30         1.23           90.72          90.9           2.37
8          102.90         1.05           97.08          90.7           2.29
9          108.57         1.37           92.78          91.3           2.43
10         105.97         1.66           95.37          89.8           2.41
11         114.33         2.97           95.08          93.3           2.21
12         103.26         2.29           96.76          93.9           2.21
13         112.08         2.21           99.04          94.5           2.32
14         112.27         2.15           97.98          94.7           2.37
15         105.50         2.22           98.85          95.2           2.31
16         112.16         2.70           91.92          95.2           2.34
17         115.25         2.74           93.14          95.4           2.37
18         106.40         2.52           96.80          95.6           2.31
19         109.38         2.47           95.41          96.2           2.32
20         111.20         3.16           97.12          95.8           2.31
```

And partitions of it:

```
set.seed(3456)

training_index <- createDataPartition(middle_sub$`Ratio at Birth`, p = 0.8, list = F)
training_set <- middle_sub[training_index, ]# Training Set
testing_set <- middle_sub[-training_index,] # Test Set
```

However, when I train the model and predicted the values from test set, I got a negative $R^2$

```
multilinear_model <- train(`Ratio at Birth` ~ ., data = training_set,
               method = "lm",
               na.action = na.omit,
               preProcess=c("scale","center"),
               trControl= trainControl(method="none")
)
```

This is the `eval_results` function to calculate the `MSE`, `Rsquare` and `MAE`

```
eval_results <- function(true, predicted, df) {
                  SSE <- sum((predicted - true)^2)
                  SST <- sum((true - mean(true))^2)
                  R_square <- 1 - SSE / SST
                  data.frame(
                    MSE = mse(true, predicted),
                    Rsquare = R_square,
                    MAE = MAE(predicted, true)
                  )
                }



prediction_reg_test <-predict(multilinear_model, newdata = testing_set) # Apply model to make prediction on Testing set
eval_results(testing_set$`Ratio at Birth`, prediction_reg_test, testing_set)
```

Which gives:

```
Rsquare
<dbl>
-1.631099
```

Is it because my model does not fit the data set? Thanks!

Comment: What packages are you using? Where does the `eval_results` function come from?

Comment: I just added the function, thank you.

Comment: My guess is the problem is that you are using ` preProcess=c("scale","center")` so the model predicting in a different scaled space. How does the range of `prediction_reg_test` compare to the range of `testing_set$`Ratio at Birth`? If you want to do your own rsquared calculations, it would probably be better to do the scaling and centering yourself first so you have access to the transformed values for further calculations.

Comment: Your `eval_results` functions is incorrect: `mean(true)` will be different for the training set and the test set. But you need to to use the training `mean(true)` for the test set as well. This is related to the issue with scaling the training & test sets separately outlined by @MrFlick.

Comment: How could I fix this calculation? Thank you.

Comment: @MrFlick You mean I should scale the test set based on those calculations?